# adding button to the navigation bar

Tags: iphone

i have a problem while adding button to the navigation bar.. My application consist of two view controllers added to the viewControllers array of a tabBarController. Inturn this tabBarController is added to the viewControllers array of a navigationController. In one of the views i have a textfield for entering dates . On the tap of this textfield the datepicker will pop up. simultaneously i want to display a done button on the navigation bar.  how can i do this... i tried using

```
self.tabBarController.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.doneButton;
```

But this is not working...

Pls help me out..

Comment: I have the same problem. Can we do this from Interface Builder?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code,

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Done", @"")
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                              target:self
                                                              action:@selector(DoneButton)] autorelease];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: thanks for ur reply can.... i tried this but this is not working.. is there any other way....?

Comment: @praseed. Thats only display the button.you can write any action in  "-(void) DoneButton{};

Comment: ya... but the button itself is not getting displayed... !

Comment: @praseed, Which Application have u used like window or view based application or navigation?

Comment: Pugal... i am new to iPhone apps development... so i cant make out wat the exact problem....in my app i have added two subclasses of table view controller in to the viewControllers array of a tabBarcontroller and this tabBarController is added to the viewControllers array of a navigation controller. one of the subclasses of tableView controller is a grouped table with cells having embedded with textfields .. when tapped on one of this textfields i am displaing a datepicker ... i want to add a done button so that i can close the date picker.. but when i tried the above method its not working..

Comment: I have used same code and it worked well. If You are used view controller and you should add navigation controller,then only you can used the above code.

Comment: but my root controller is a navigation controller ... am i right...?

Comment: so why should i add a navigation controller... i didnt get that .... am i going wrong in my concepts...

Comment: okay. I have one question. Have you seen navigation bar in that particular view (Which you want to display the done button).

Comment: If you want to add navigation controller in your delegate method. But you have used table view controller means it doesnt need.

Comment: ok so wat ur suggetions so that i can modify the application... Pls can u explain it....

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
UIBarButtonItem* _doneButton;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = _doneButton;
```

Comment: espuz... i tried this... but.. not working... thanx for ur reply... any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

use this one:

```
UIButton *myBtn = [[UIButton alloc]init];
[self.navigationItem.titleView addSubview:myBtn];
```